# How to get items of a repeater row and column into an array or list in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

i have a repeater bounded with records from from a source. the content of the repeater looks like this

```
  Science       5             67

  Art           3             57
```

at the end of the day, i want to get the result of this repeater like this `{Science, Art}{5,3}{67,57}` so i can save into the database. If you have any other way i can get to save that table in the database for a particular Student, Kindly suggest.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeater_ItemDataBound">
  <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td class="ctg-type">
        <strong> <%#Eval("SubjectName") %> </strong> <span><strong> <%#Eval("Unit") %></strong></span>
      </td>
      <td class="cgt-des">
        <%# Eval("Score") %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  repeater.DataSource = getSudentRecord();
  repeater.DataBind();
}

public DataTable getStudentRecord()
{
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("StudentRecord", con))
  {
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    con.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    var data = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    var Table = new DataTable();
    data.Fill(Table);
    con.Close();
    return Table;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify: you retrieve the data **for** the repeater **from** the db and then you want to save the data **from** the repeater **to** the db. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: "result of this repeater". What does this mean? The user updates something in fields within the repeater? It's not at all clear exactly what you mean. You need to show some actual code I think

Comment: To make it clearly. The table above is displayed using a repeater. The rows and column could change. What i want to do though, is to get the content of the repeater above in this manner {Science, Art}{5,3}{67,57} and then save in the database. What i want to do is to save get the content of the table(repeater) above and save it to database.

Comment: Please post the code part where you bind the Repeater to a datasource.

Comment: And the code behind ? Somewhere it has to be something like this:

var foo =  // something with at least 3 columns (SubjectName, Unit,Score)
repeater.DataSource = foo;
repeater.DataBind();

What type is foo ?

I think you should parse directly the datasource and do not involve the repeater.

Comment: Ok. So the user is not changing anything.  You can examine the Datatable which is the result of `getSudentRecord()` to find your desired information. Far easier than trying to traverse the Repeater, which is a GUI component and not designed for querying. Also, since you are fetching this data from a database already, why do you need to save it back again in a slightly bizarre string format - what is the actual purpose of this?

Answer (score 1):

This approach will parse the DataTable twice:

```
        DataTable foo = getSudentRecord();

        string serializedFormat = "{{{0}}},{{{1}}},{{{2}}}";
        List<string> subjectnames = new List<string>();
        List<string> units = new List<string>();
        List<string> scores = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow row in foo.Rows)
        {
            subjectnames.Add(row["SubjectName"].ToString());
            units.Add(row["Unit"].ToString());
            scores.Add(row["Score"].ToString());
        }

        string serialized = String.Format(serializedFormat,
            String.Join(",",subjectnames.ToArray()),
            String.Join(",", units.ToArray()),
            String.Join(",", scores.ToArray())
            );


        //finally fill the repeater
        repeater.DataSource = foo;
        repeater.DataBind();
```